# Не передаются данные через сокеты в Java

Tags: java, сокеты

Суть проблемы в заголовке. Как это решить?
Код сервера:

```
public class TestServer {

public static ServerSocket server;
public static Socket client;

public static Thread waitThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                TestServer.client = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected! " + client.getInetAddress().toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(4444);
        waitThread.start();

        while (true) {
            if (client != null) {
                BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                String line = null;
                if ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Код клиента:

```
public class TestClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);

        while (true) {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            out.write("Kek");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Kek");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static volatile Socket client;
```